# Ignoring old multiple asynchronous ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I've got a custom javascript autocomplete script that hits the server with multiple asynchronous ajax requests.  (Everytime a key gets pressed.)

I've noticed that sometimes an earlier ajax request will be returned after a later requests, which messes things up.

The way I handle this now is I have a counter that increments for each ajax request.  Requests that come back with a lower count get ignored.

I'm wondering:  Is this proper?  Or is there a better way of dealing with this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Travis

Comment: I think sending an ajax request every time a key is pressed is a recipe for overloading yoru server when you get a couple simultaneous users.  Try throttling the thing by setting up a delay timer so the request is only sent if no key is pressed for a half-second, then you'd only get one hit when the user stops typing.  This comment for example could have created 383 server hits...

Comment: @Karl, Agreed, but this could still be an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store a "global" `currentAjaxRequest`, which holds the structure of the last XHR request.  Then you can `abort` the current request when you make a new one.

For example:

```
var currentAjaxRequest = null;

function autoCompleteStuff() {
    if(currentAjaxRequest !== null) {
        currentAjaxRequest.abort();
    }

    currentAjaxRequest = $.get(..., function(...) {
        currentAjaxRequest = null;

        ...
    });
}
```

To avoid naming conflicts, wrap that in an anonymous, instantly-executed function, if needed.